# Looking for a word that means provoking introspection

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective that means provoking introspection. Thought-provoking is close to the adjective I'm looking for but I would like a word that is more specific. Thought-provoking doesn't work since thought-provoking can lead to introspective thoughts but it can also lead to thinking about, for instance, politics.

Basically, I'm looking for an adjective that would describe a piece of work that causes a lot of introspective thoughts.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do any better than ***instrospective-provoking***. But why not that?

Comment: Introspection-provoking has too many syllables. I feel like there's got to be a better word but that may be the best we've got.

Comment: _introvoking_? (sometimes you gotta neologize...)

Answer (score 5):

Might the word be *[evocative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evocative)*:
bringing thoughts, memories, or feelings into the mind;
evoking or tending to evoke an especially emotional response.

1. "settings... so *evocative* that they bring tears to the eyes" — Eric Malpass.
2. He wrote a powerful and *evocative* biography.
3. the Italian-American restaurant is decorated in a manner *evocative* of the charming outdoor cafés in Italy.

adverb: evocatively.

noun: evocativeness.

Synonyms:
suggestive, reminiscent.

Answer (score 2):

The following behaviours suggest a search for introspection:

[Soul-searching](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soul-searching):

> - displaying the characteristics of deep  self-analysis.

and 
 [self-analytical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-analytical) :

> - relating to or using self-analysis

Answer (score 0):

**Thought-provoking** (adjective): prompting serious thought; no synonymn

Comment: Thought-provoking is close to the word I'm looking for but I would like a word that is more specific. Thought-provoking doesn't work since thought-provoking can lead to introspective thoughts but it can also lead to thinking about, for instance, politics.

Comment: ...and God forbid that anyone should think about politics!

Comment: That's not my point at all. If I tell someone, "this book was thought-provoking" it gives them no information as to what thoughts it provoked. I want a word that says "this book provoked introspective thoughts".

Comment: @NewNameStat Well why don't you say that?

Comment: I could say that but I'm looking for a less-wordy version. Perhaps there isn't one though.

Comment: Your comment prompts serious thought.  See, I didn't use "very" as in "prompts very serious thought."

Answer (score 0):

"**Reverie-inducing**" could be used to describe something which casts you into [a brown study.](http://www.theparisreview.org/blog/2015/02/03/golden-brown/)

Answer (score 0):

> **Tending to promote *self-reflection***
>
> **self-reflection**
>
> *noun*: self-reflection: meditation or serious thought about one's character, actions, and motives
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=self+reflective+define&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> Human self-reflection is the capacity of humans to exercise introspection and the willingness to learn more about their fundamental nature, purpose and essence. The earliest historical records demonstrate the great interest which humanity has had in itself. Human self-reflection invariably leads to inquiry into the human condition and the essence of humankind as a whole
>
> [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_self-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[contemplative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemplative)*

> involving, allowing, or causing deep thought

*Merriam-Webster*

Answer (score -1):

1. **Reflect** (in the right context) "The painting caused Gustav to
   reflect." Or "The painting reflected Gustav's feelings."
2. It is not a well-known word, but it could lead you down a path to a word you do like: **Pratyahara** is a yogic practice of turning your attention inward.
3. **Challenging** (again, context is important)

This is a tough one.